# how to get login email and password of kubeflow dashboard?

Tags: kubeflow

I'm using microk8s with kubeflow on ubuntu 20.4. When I deploy kubeflow for the first time using the cmd "microk8s enable kubeflow", it gives a user id and password, and dashboard URL. but when I go to the URL, it shows a login page with email and password fields. so how can I get the "user-id" field here instead of email? I also have tried default "admin@kubeflow.org:123456", also not working.

Answer (score 0):

user id is equal to the email filed here. so just paste your user id in the email filed.